# iptables nat balancing using statistics extension

Tags: linux, iptables, nat

I'm trying to replace new connection source ports and round robin them from my pool of ports. Here is my iptables config for pool of 2 ports.

```
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 25 -o eth0 -m statistic --mode nth --every 2 --packet 0  -j SNAT --to :30000
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 25 -o eth0 -m statistic --mode nth --every 2 --packet 1  -j SNAT --to :30001
```

As you can see I am matching with connection destination port on 25.
So when I use telnet to test the configuration. First telnet (connection) source port will be 30000 as expected.

Second telnet will be 30001 as expected.

The third telnet however will miss the NAT table and will go out with its random source port.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any other firewall rules? I've deleted my answer because I was doing the opposite: balancing inbound; but it was almost exactly the same command.

Comment: No, I flushed Iptables, Then added those 2 stated above.

Comment: I know figuring this is pretty hard , but why downvotes?! :D